# angular-cli Firebase hosting Angular 2 router not working

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-hosting

I am trying to host an angular 2 app (created with angular cli) with Firebase but my routes are not working.

I created a project with angular 2 and typescript for a site I am working on where I want a static privacy-policy page.

When I perform

```
ng serve
```

and navigate to http://localhost:4200/privacy-policy in my browser I get the content I expect.

Here is the code as recommended by the angular 2 route page-

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        HomeComponent,
        TermsOfServiceComponent,
        PrivacyPolicyComponent,
        PageNotFoundComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        AlertModule,
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        HttpModule,
        RouterModule.forRoot([
            {path: 'privacy-policy', component: PrivacyPolicyComponent},
            {path: 'terms-of-service', component: TermsOfServiceComponent},
            {path: '', component: HomeComponent},
            {path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent}
        ])
    ],
    providers: [],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

I configured Firebase hosting with my project here is my config file-

```
{
  "database": {
    "rules": "database.rules.json"
  },
  "hosting": {
    "public": "dist"
  }
}
```

To Deploy I run

```
ng build --prod
firebase deploy
```

When I navigate to
https://MY-APP.firebaseapp.com/
The app loads fine for the default route.

However when I try to navigate to
https://MY-APP.firebaseapp.com/privacy-policy
I get 404.

I would have expected this to work as it did with ng serve.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In your `app.module.ts` file just add following things:

declare

```
import { LocationStrategy, HashLocationStrategy} from '@angular/common';
```

and in providers add following

```
   @NgModule({
        declarations: [...],
        imports:[...],
        providers:[..,{ provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy },..]
        ...,
    })
```

Hope this will solve your problem.

And if possible keep your Routes in separate file.

Cheers

Comment: This fixed my issue.  To clarify, you are saying that in firebase hosting using angular js I need to use the URL fragment for the full path. https://MY-APP.firebaseapp.com/#/privacy-policy

Answer (score 49):

Late response, but since i faced the same problem today when i deployed my app on Firebase, here is the quick fix for it:

In your **firebase.json** file, update your hosting key by defining **rewrite** rules:

```
  "hosting": {
    "public": "dist",
    "rewrites": [ {
      "source": "**",
      "destination": "/index.html"
    } ]
  }
```

Comment: That's the answer as I don't want to use the HashLocationStrategy in my WebApp. Thanks @Vlad

Comment: can anyone explain why does mapping every non-matching url to index.html can solve this issue? and it didn't work for me at all, it turns out that for every static asset I have, I got an index.html, i.e. cordova.js, main.css

Comment: and what about if I have a server side rendered app and I need to point the `destanation` to the **firebase function**?

Comment: Does anyone have a link to some docs about this, please? Worked for me, but I'd like to know a little more about what's happening behind. And thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Open firebase.json

if you have this:

```
    "ignore": [
  "firebase.json",
  "**/.*",
  "**/node_modules/**"
]
```

remove the **/.* line

so you have this:

```
"ignore": [
  "firebase.json",
  "**/node_modules/**"
]
```

left me with this and worked:

```
    {
  "database": {
    "rules": "database.rules.json"
  },
  "firestore": {
    "rules": "firestore.rules",
    "indexes": "firestore.indexes.json"
  },
  "hosting": {
    "public": "dist",
    "rewrites": [ {
      "source": "**",
      "destination": "/index.html"
    } ],
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I am on Angular 8 and this worked for me

ng build --prod
firebase deploy

Also my firebase.json file looks like below:

```
    {
        "hosting": {
         "public": "dist/crm",
         "ignore": [
            "firebase.json",
            "**/.*",
            "**/node_modules/**"
         ],
         "rewrites": [
          {
            "source": "**",
            "destination": "/index.html"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
```

In dist/crm, crm is the name of the project folder. I hope it helps.